# (PHP) Post form containing a table with checkboxes

Tags: php

Let's assume I have a table in a form, containing inputs and checkboxes:

```
<form method='post' action=''>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Select</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name=table[code][] type='text' value='C001' /></td
            <td><input name=table[description][] type='text' value='Object 1' /></td>
            <td><input name=table[select][] type='checkbox' checked /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name=table[code][] type='text' value='C002' /></td
            <td><input name=table[description][] type='text' value='Object 2' /></td>
            <td><input name=table[select][] type='checkbox' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name=table[code][] type='text' value='C003' /></td
            <td><input name=table[description][] type='text' value='Object 3' /></td>
            <td><input name=table[select][] type='checkbox' checked /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

The table is populated by PHP and extended by the user (through a jQuery script), so I cannot know how many rows I'll have when the form is posted

in $_POST I find these values (not PHP code, just showing $_POST content):

```
$_POST['table']['code'][0] = C001
$_POST['table']['code'][1] = C002
$_POST['table']['code'][2] = C003

$_POST['table']['description'][0] = Object 1
$_POST['table']['description'][1] = Object 2
$_POST['table']['description'][2] = Object 3

$_POST['table']['select'][0] = 1
$_POST['table']['select'][1] = 1
```

As you can see, I have no correlation between 'select' fields and 'code/description'

My solution was to add the index of the array, like this:

```
<td><input name=table[code][1] type='text' value='C001' /></td>
<td><input name=table[description][1] type='text' value='Object 1' /></td>
<td><input name=table[select][1] type='checkbox' checked /></td>
```

and checking `if(isset(&_POST['table']['select'][1]))`

but this doesn't feel an elegant solution to me, as it require to number the fields as the table is populated and update numbers in jQuery as new rows are added.

Is there a better solution for keeping each row's input together?

Comment: I would agree that this _is_ the best solution. Yes, you might have to put a little more effort into your client-side coding to add rows to the form - but this is the only way that gives you the data in a structured form that allows to relate the different values to one another, even if some might be “missing.”

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is the best one, you have to group your correlated fields together, and, since the `checkbox` element arent sent if not checked, the best way to do that is with a unique id.

Still, there are other solutions. Off the top of my head, there's this one, which involves a bit of `jQuery` and is ugly as f**k, but should work :

```
<form method='post' action=''>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Select</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="table[code][]" type='text' value='C001' /></td>
            <td><input name="table[description][]" type='text' value='Object 1' /></td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" checked />
                <input name="table[checkbox][]" value="1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="table[code][]" type='text' value='C002' /></td>
            <td><input name="table[description][]" type='text' value='Object 2' /></td>
            <td>
                <input type='checkbox' checked />
                <input name="table[checkbox][]" value="0" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="table[code][]" type='text' value='C003' /></td
            <td><input name="table[description][]" type='text' value='Object 3' /></td>
            <td>
                <input type='checkbox' checked />
                <input name="table[checkbox][]" value="1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
        var target = $(this).parent('td').find('input[type="hidden"]');
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            target.val(1);
        } else {
            target.val(0);
        }
    });
</script>
```

I deleted the `name` attributes from your checkboxes and added `hidden` fields with the same name.

When a checkbox's state changes (from checked to unchecked and vice-versa), the jQuery bit will set the corresponding `hidden` input value to either `1` (if the checkbox is cheked) or `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a value as well in your checkbox input. Then, you can check it against your code when submitting it.

I have not tested the above code, but I would do something along that.

```
<td><input name=table[code][] type='text' value='C003' /></td>
<td><input name=table[description][] type='text' value='Object 3' /></td>
<td><input name=table[select] value='C003' type='checkbox' checked /></td>
```

And in your back-end:

```
$checkedCodes = explode(',', $_POST['table']['select']); //all the values would be separated by ,
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['table']['code']; $i++) {
    $code = $_POST['table']['code'][$i];
    $description = $_POST['table']['description'][$i];
    $checked = in_array($checkedCodes, $code);
}
```